# Install golang the easy way

Tags: software-installation, golang

I'd like to use the Pis with Raspbian to run Go code. For this, I like to write an easy and fast setup guide from the point you erase the SD card. During the development, I installed Go on the Pis with [this](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/25/installing-go-on-the-raspberry-pi) guide. It has some deficiencies but works fine. My only problem is, that we have to install mercurial just for cloning the sources: `hg clone -u default https://code.google.com/p/go $HOME/go`
The installation of mercurial on Pi is really slow. I'd like to ask how to work it around (It's not a problem if I don't build it from source.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's already a go compiler in, e.g., raspbian, which you can find with `apt-cache search golang`.  This looks to be version 1.0.2.

The site you linked has pre-compiled tarballs of 1.3.3 available for the pi.  You just need to download the appropriate one -- it is clearly indicated.

Put the tarball in `/usr/local` and:

```
tar -xzf go.1.3.3.linux-arm~multiarch-armv6-1.tar.gz
```

This will create a `go` directory; the top level README refers to the contents as the go source, but if you look in the `bin` directory, you'll see the precompiled `go` executable there.  To make this generally useful you'll have to get that into `$PATH`.  Add a file to `/etc/profile.d` called `go.sh` with one line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
```

If there's already a go installed, this will now supersede that. I'm not a go user so I don't know if much more is necessary, but if you look in the `doc` directory there's lots of stuff there, including an `install.html` file.

Comment: another +1 for sudo apt-get install golang

Answer (score 16):

As of Go 1.6 (February 2016), an official ARMv6 package is [available for download](https://golang.org/dl/). So, if your Raspberry Pi has ARMv6 or v7 (see `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep ARM`), then just [do something like](https://tip.golang.org/doc/install):

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.6.2.linux-armv6l.tar.gz 
sudo tar -xzf go1.6.2.linux-armv6l.tar.gz -C /usr/local
sudo chgrp -R staff /usr/local/go
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH="$PATH:$GOROOT/bin"
```

The above is fast, and less cumbersome than [building 1.5+ from source](https://golang.org/s/go15bootstrap):

> To build Go 1.x, for x ≥ 5, it will be necessary to have Go 1.4 (or newer) installed already, in $GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP.

Answer (score 2):

Should be as simple as

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

there are other mercurial packages that can be found via

```
sudo apt-cache search mercurial
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a super easy way to install the very latest Golang version for your Raspberry PI.

*Find the lastest release version tag, download the pkg, and install it*

```
export GOPKG="$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/git/matching-refs/tags/go | grep ref | grep -v url | grep -v beta | tail -1 | awk -F\/ {' print $3 '} | sed 's/",//')"
wget https://golang.org/dl/$GOPKG.linux-armv6l.tar.gz
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf $GOPKG.linux-armv6l.tar.gz
rm $GOPKG.linux-armv6l.tar.gz
```

*Setup the shell*

```
# for zsh
echo PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin >> $HOME/.zshrc
echo GOPATH=$HOME/golang >> $HOME/.zshrc
source $HOME/.zshrc
```

I wrote this up in a blog post on my website for easy reference:
[Golang on Raspberry PI (Easiest)](https://d4v3y0rk.com/golang-on-rpi-easiest/)